# how to add integer to a list

Tags: apex

I'm trying to add numbers to an integer list but I'm receiving an error. Please refer my code

```
public class TstListofIntegers {

    public void testInteger() {
        List<Integer> listOfIntegers;

        for(Integer i=0;i<10;i++)
        {        
            listOfIntegers.add(i);
        }

        system.debug('listofIntegers'+listOfIntegers);
    }
}
```

**Error:** `System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Initialize your list `List<Integer> listOfIntegers = new List<Integer>();`

Comment: alright , feel free to accept answer if its working for you ! there will be ✓  sign at left side.